# Problems with in place value setting with Panel

Tags: python, pandas

having real issues with value setting data from Dataframes into panels, will explain with some code

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import *
foo = DataFrame(np.nan,index=date_range('2014-05-01','2014-05-8'),columns=['a','b'])
bar= Panel({'foob':foo.copy(),'barb':foo.copy()})
foo[:]=1.0
```

ok, so these two below work as expected...

```
bar.ix['foob',0,0] = foo.ix[0,0].copy()
bar.ix['foob',:,:]
bar.ix['foob',:,0] = foo.ix[:,0].copy()
bar.ix['foob',:,:]
```

but when I try to set the whole 'foob' Item (Dataframe) it resets values to nan's

```
bar.ix['foob',:,:] = foo.ix[:,:].copy()
bar.ix['foob',:,:]

             a   b
2014-05-01 NaN NaN
2014-05-02 NaN NaN
2014-05-03 NaN NaN
2014-05-04 NaN NaN
2014-05-05 NaN NaN
2014-05-06 NaN NaN
2014-05-07 NaN NaN
2014-05-08 NaN NaN
```

The Question is ...I'm trying to set the values on the Panel using the index values of another data object, but I get a ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape, which is odd as the shape look the same ?

```
bar.ix['foob',foo.index[1:],foo.columns[1:]] = foo.ix[foo.index[1:],foo.columns[1:]].copy()
```

there is a work around but its not ideal( especially with large structures) by creating a new dataframe object (foobar in this case), doing the indexed value setting on that which works like a charm, then replacing the whole item in the Panel

```
foobar = bar.ix['foob',:,:].copy()
foobar.ix[foo.index[1:],foo.columns[1:]] = foo.ix[foo.index[1:],foo.columns[1:]]
bar['foob'] = footer
bar['foob']

             a   b
2014-05-01 NaN NaN
2014-05-02 NaN   1
2014-05-03 NaN   1
2014-05-04 NaN   1
2014-05-05 NaN   1
2014-05-06 NaN   1
2014-05-07 NaN   1
2014-05-08 NaN   1
```

Does anyone know how to set the values of a Panel in place using the indexes of another data object as above without having to create a new Dataframe, many thanks

Comment: this is a known issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3777, your work-around is the correct method; you will often find better performance by swaping axes to make axis 0 the axis you are setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific example, this will work

```
In [12]: bar['foob'] = foo.ix[:,:].copy()
# bar.ix['foob'] also works

In [13]: bar.values
Out[13]: 
array([[[ nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan]],

       [[  1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.]]])
```

when you specify multiple axis indexers (the `:`) this sends in theory should treat them the same, might be a bug lurking.

Comment: thanks Jeff, think you are right also bar.ix['foob',:,:] = foo.values , works , but can't get the multi axis indexed setting to work at all

Comment: as I said, might be a bug; that code is quite tricky. If you post a simple reproducible example on github will take a look.